# mod_cgi + utf8 + Python3 produces no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, utf-8, cgi

If you create this `app.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n")
print("Hello World!")
```

and you enable CGI in `.htaccess` with:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

it totally works: http://example.com/app.py displays "Hello world!".

However if you add an accented character:

```
print("Quel été!")
```

this does not work anymore: the output page is empty in the browser.

**Question: how to output a UTF8 content with Python3 + `mod_cgi`?**

NB:

- the .py file is saved with UTF8 encoding.
- Might be related: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2471
- Fun fact: running

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
  import sys
  print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n")
  print(str(sys.stdout.encoding))
  ```

  from command-line gives `UTF-8` but running it trough `mod_cgi` outputs `ANSI_X3.4-1968` in http://example.com/app.py.

  Setting `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` did not change anything, probably because it's Apache + mod_cgi that calls this Python code.

Comment: Probably there's an (encoding-related) exception which doesn't show in the browser (you'd expect an error 500, but I haven't ever used Python CGI, so I don't know). There's some environment-based heuristics involved in setting the encoding of the STD streams when the Python interpreter is started; see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout). On a *nix platform, you might be able to fix this via the `PYTHONIOENCODING` env variable.

Comment: @lenz I just did a few tests, I edited the question (see last point); it seems that doing `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` in bash did not change anything. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easy solution

Just add:

```
SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf8
```

in the `.htaccess`, along with:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

See also [overwrite python3 default encoder when using apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731852/overwrite-python3-default-encoder-when-using-apache-server) and [Problème python apache et utf8](https://linuxfr.org/forums/programmation-python/posts/probleme-python-apache-et-utf8-resolu). Also related but no answers did directly solve it: [Set encoding in Python 3 CGI scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322410/set-encoding-in-python-3-cgi-scripts).

### Alternate solution

For Python 3 - 3.6 (see [How to set sys.stdout encoding in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3)):

```
import sys, codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

For Python 3.7+:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

---

Note: even if it is sometimes cited in some answers, the following script **does not work** with Apache 2.4 + mod_cgi + Python3:

```
import locale                                  # Ensures that subsequent open()s 
locale.getpreferredencoding = lambda: 'UTF-8'  # are UTF-8 encoded.
import sys
sys.stdin = open('/dev/stdin', 'r')            # Re-open standard files in UTF-8 
sys.stdout = open('/dev/stdout', 'w')          # mode.
sys.stderr = open('/dev/stderr', 'w') 
print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n")
print(str(sys.stdout.encoding))  # I still get: ANSI_X3.4-1968
```