# Setting stdout UTF8 encoding with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, io

I have carefully read answers from [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python) but:

- the solution `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` does not work if you're not calling the process yourself. Example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879593/mod-cgi-utf8-python3-produces-no-output) the process is called from Apache + mod_cgi, and running `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` in Bash does not change anything; I still have `import sys; print(str(sys.stdout.encoding))` giving `ANSI_X3.4-1968`.
- the solution

  ```
  import sys, codecs
  sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
  ```

  probably worked on Python 2.7 but not really for Python 3, because then, `print(s)` expects `s` being bytes, which is not very handy

Should we use a way to permanently `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` **for all processes of the system** (that is persistent, even after a reboot), if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, the solution is to use `SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf8` in `.htaccess` files, as detailed here: [mod_cgi + utf8 + Python3 produces no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879593/mod-cgi-utf8-python3-produces-no-output/61885959#61885959).

For other processes it might be interesting to put `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8`  in `/etc/environment` for persistence (not sure if it does the job for all processes that could call a Python script).